# Validate property key from property data in JSON Schema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I need to validate the following:
Json data:
{ tag: 'picture',
picture: 'some string  '}

Json schema: 
{ tag: {'type': 'string'}, 
???????  // The second key should be the data value of the 'tag'

Edit: I wish to accomplish this with ajv schema validator

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $data reference (requires $data option):

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "tag": {"type": "string"}
  },
  "additionalProperties": {}, // any schema for the second property value
  "propertyNames": {
    "anyOf": [
      {"const": "tag"},
      {"const": {"$data": "1/tag"} }
    ]
  }
}
```

[$data is a proposal](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51) for the next versions of JSON schema.

See https://runkit.com/esp/59e0d803bf8366001374c2a2